# Android OnItemClick show image in fullscreen mode

Tags: android, image, listview, fullscreen, swipe

I'm working on a project where I'm using a custom made List View with images and text.I'm trying to find a way to show an image in fullscreen mode when I select an item from List View. So for now I have this :

```
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.all_stampii_listview);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) 
            {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Images.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Actually here is a sample of what I want to do with Javascript : http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/jquery-mobile.html#&ui-state=dialog

More information of what I want to do:
When I click the ListView item i need to show the image with unique ID on fullscreen mode and after I click it once I need to show a custom made menu like in the example made with Javascript.And the final thing I want to be able to swipe between different images on fullscreen mode.
So can anyone help me,show me,give me some example,or some useful information how to do that.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Copying the below code to onCreate of an activity would show it in FullScreen mode.

In your case, you need to put the code into onCreate() of Images Activity.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Shash

Comment: Ok,but I need to be able to swipe between images,without using ViewFlipper.Any ideas how to do that?